# Dynamic Extjs DateFields in the dynamic form

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, extjs

I am very much thankful to this stackoverflow,as i am getting required help very quickly here.

I am facing a problem in ExtJs.(with java spring backend combination). I am having a jsp file like this.

```
<c:when test="${eformDetails.controlType=='date'}">
    <span id="eform_date_${eformDetails.id}"></span>            
</c:when>
```

And in the js file i am trying to create date objects like this.But not working :-(

```
$.each('span[id^=["eform_date_"]',function(){new Ext.form.DateField({renderTo:this.id,name: 'form_0',id :'date_'+this.id,width: 140});});
```

My Requirement is if the `eformDetails.controlType` is date then i have to display a date field there.

Could please help me in this.

I am very much thankful to you guys..

Thanks in advance
-Sathya

Answer (score 0):

The selector you're looking for is probably:

```
$.each('span[id^=eform_date_]', function() { /* DateField */ });
```

The unmatched bracket is a syntax error. You can test it in your browser's console to make sure you're getting it right.

Comment: This jsp file is Ext.Window. FYI

Comment: More detail than "not working" will help determine what the issue is. How is it not working? When you run the selector in the browser's console, do you get the spans you are targetting?